# Spring RestTemplate Row Mapper

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate, spring-rest

Java - spring RestTemplate

using following code to get rest response

PropsNotMatchClass notMatchClass;

```
ResponseEntity<PerfectPropsMatchClass> resp= restTemplate.getForEntity(url, PerfectPropsMatchClass.class)
PerfectPropsMatchClass props = resp.getBody();
```

i had to create PerfectPropsMatchClass class b/c my PropsNotMatchClass didn't had exact names as in returned response. is there a efficient way i can iterate on each row in response and create objects of  PropsNotMatchClass.

Comment: Why don't you extract the response in a string class and iterate over the field you are looking for and then create the class instance?

Comment: is that a preffered way of doing it ?

Comment: I would say preferred sometimes end up as one's way of seeing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use ResponseExtractor.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/ResponseExtractor.html

It is used in RestTemplate as such.

```
<T> T execute(String url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback, ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor, Map<String,?> uriVariables)
```

Comment: can you please give example of calling execute method